# Regex to find any string that starts with $ and ends with()

Tags: php, regex

I am horrible at regex and this is all I got.

```
\$(w.*)\(
```

I want to match anything between $ and () that isn't a space or new line, basically any word between $ and () So match:

$hey()

$ya_whatup()

$okHello(

Edit: I am using this in PhpStorm to find variable functions in my code.

Comment: Then use `\$\w+\(\)`

Comment: `(?<=\$)[^ \n]*(?=\(\)){1}`